# monerod system time

Tags: monerod, linux

monerod logs (to bitmonero.log) a different time than the one my Linux OS is configured for.
It seems like another timezone (-2 hours from my OS).
How can I set up monerod to use the same time and timezone as my OS?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

monerod logs using UTC for privacy reasons (to not leak your timezone should you need to share your logs).

If you really want your logs to be in your timezone, you can replace "gmtime" with "localtime", in the places this patch changed (ie, revert that patch):

https://github.com/monero-project/monero/commit/977c2186c9f126b56e714698f6be94ea5751d8b9

Comment: Thank you for the answer, now it makes sense :) Thanks for the correction of my english as well.